# Android ImageView set image according to tag

Tags: android, android-imageview, android-resources

I was wondering if there was any way in Android to set an `ImageView`'s image dynamically by using its `tag`.

Ideally it would be like this:

```
// image_view_style.xml
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
  <item android:tag="1"
        android:drawable="@drawable/image_for_tag_1"/>
  <item android:tag="2"
        android:drawable="@drawable/image_for_tag_2"/>
  <item android:tag="3"
        android:drawable="@drawable/image_for_tag_3"/>
</selector>
```

And simply calling the `ImageView`'s `setTag()` method with the value I want.

I tried this but it doesn't work. Is there any clean way to do the image selection in the resource file (for something else than `state_selected`, `state_pressed`, etc) ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you can use `LevelListDrawable` to achieve what you want:

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/LevelListDrawable.html

From the documentation:

```
<level-list xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
<item android:maxLevel="0" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_wifi_signal_1" />
<item android:maxLevel="1" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_wifi_signal_2" />
<item android:maxLevel="2" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_wifi_signal_3" />
<item android:maxLevel="3" android:drawable="@drawable/ic_wifi_signal_4" />
</level-list>
```

then use `setLevel(...)` in code to set a level.